# Is this method applicable in all such geometry questions?

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

The Problem statement is:

> An ant leaves the anthill for its morning exercise. It walks 4 feet east and then makes a 160° turn to the right and walks 4 more feet. It then makes another 160° turn to the right and walks 4 more feet. If the ant continues this pattern until it reaches the anthill again, how many turns would it have to take at minimum?

I found an interesting method to solve this problem, which is very similar to the way we solved this problem from IOQM 2020-21:
[Credits: Allen Career Institute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewvbv.jpg)

We can use a similar analogy in this question by assuming two concentric circles, to one of which (smaller circle) the paths followed by the ant are tangent and are equal chords of the other (bigger) circle.

Here AB is 4 and angle formed is $(180-160)=20$:

[image]

Then using similar calculations and method we get Total Number of chords = $360/\gcd(160, 360)$.

Just one problem:

> I am unable to see a way to prove that all these would be tangent to the inner circle. I first saw the answer and then thought about this method. It fortunately works, but I cannot understand how. Can we generalise this method for any value of the length of path and degree of turn?
>
> If yes, how can you prove it?

Comment: *"I am unable to see a way to prove that all these would be tangent to the inner circle."* ... Congruent chords in a circle are equidistant from the center. To see why, simply join the center to the midpoint and an endpoint of each chord, and show that these (necessarily-right) triangles are congruent. Thus, the center-to-chord distance is the same for all chords, making the chords tangent to the circle whose radius is that distance.

Comment: Keyword ["stellated polygons"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellation)

Comment: The method has nothing to do with the inner circle. The ant makes $n$ turns of $160°$ and to have the same orientation as at start $n\cdot 160°$ must be a multiple of $360°$. The minimum $n$ is then $$n={\operatorname{lcm}(160,360)\over160}={360\over\gcd(160,360)}.$$

Comment: The angle subtended by an arc with the center of the circle is twice the angle subtended by the same arc with a vertex lying elsewhere on the circle. So the $20^\circ$ angles seen subtend $40^\circ$ arcs between the vertices, so there are $\frac{360^\circ}{40^\circ} = 9$ arcs, and thus $9$ vertices and $9$ connecting chords.

Comment: How do I prove that the vertices of the “star shaped pattern” followed by the ant will lie on a circle?